# How can I map numbers to their string equivalents in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am writing a script using DBI to execute a select query to an Oracle db. I have successfully able to capture the data but I need help to change the output.

Below is the sample output.

```
Type
2
6
```

I want to display 2=>Good and 6=>Bad

Can anyone please suggest me the Perl code to map the output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually the easiest way is to change directly the values outputted by the SQL query. With Oracle you can use [DECODE](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_decode_function.htm).

```
SELECT DECODE(MY_TYPE, 2, 'TWO', 6, 'SIX', 'DEFAULT_VALUE') FROM MY_TABLE
```

The standard SQL way is to use a CASE conditional expression. It is a little more verbose, but more powerful and more portable. It works for example in [Oracle](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/case_when.html), [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-conditional.html) and [MS-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms181765.aspx).

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN MY_TYPE = 2 THEN 'TWO'
        WHEN MY_TYPE = 6 THEN 'SIX'
        ELSE 'DEFAULT_VALUE'
    END CASE 
FROM MY_TABLE
```

If you still want to do it in Perl, you might create a [Hash](http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2006/11/02/all-about-hashes.html). The code sample is quite trivial, and well documented in the link I provided.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I have tried DECODE and its working. Is there any way to do the same in postgres also OR should I have to use perl only for this.

Comment: @Octopus: I edited the answer to add the portable way to do it. (I didn't since you only mentioned Oracle at first, and DECODE is *much* simpler to use)

Answer (score 6):

```
# Create a hash of the values you want to output
my %human_text = (2 => 'Good', 6 => 'Bad');

# and then access the hash values like this:
print $human_text{2}; #will output 'Good'
print $human_text{6}; #will output 'Bad'
```

Comment: +1 @okko.net for the Perl solution but it is better to do data transformation on the SQL side.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür: Why it's better to do data transformation on the SQL side ? The data transformation here is a 'displaying job', I don't see any reason to give it to SQL side... Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a lookup table in your RDBMS which maps 2 to Good and 6 to Bad.  Create an INNER JOIN (or LEFT JOIN if you anticipate having values that will not match the lookup) with your SQL statement (or create a VIEW which returns the JOINed tables).  Trying to use Perl or SQL SELECT statements to replace database design is probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

$inWords = ("","very good","good","satisfactory","sufficient","poor","bad")[$number];